# picking file for async-http file upload (uri to file path)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-async-http

I know my problem has been tackled multiple times already, but I couldn't find anything that would help me with my specific problem.

I have an intent to pick a file anywhere from the system:

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

I pick up this intent here:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file
                Uri uri = data.getData();
```

}

and I have an upload method like so:

```
private void upload(File file){
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    try {
        params.put("fileToUpload", file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post("http://...", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            System.out.println("statusCode "+statusCode);//statusCode 200
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
}
```

the problem is that I don't know how to "marry" the two methods onActivity and upload because I don't know how to process the information I get from the intent so that the AsyncHttpClient can use it.

I tried converting the Uri to an absolute path, but couldn't manage (the solutions online that seemed to work where specifically for images). I also can't "convert" the uri to a file either.

Any way I could do this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal solution is to use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`, then pass that `InputStream` to your HTTP client API for use in uploading.

If your HTTP client API does not support the use of `InputStream` or something that could be derived from one (e.g., `Reader`), and so you need a `File`, use that `InputStream` and a `FileOutputStream` on some file that you control to make a local copy of the content (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`). Then, use your local copy for the file upload operation, and delete the local copy when you are done.

Comment: Yes, thank you, Async-Http allows for an input stream instead of a File.